# Pattern matching not exhaustive

Tags: ocaml

New to learning OCaml and don't seem to get how to fix this question I found online.

```
(* Remove contiguous duplicates from a lost *)
# let rec destutter list =
    match list with 
    | [] -> []
    | hd1 :: hd2 :: tl -> 
        if hd1 = hd2 then destutter (hd2 :: tl)
        else hd1 :: destutter (hd2 :: tl)
    ;;
```

I've to enumerate all the cases, but not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Damn, I wasn't able to code format on mobile web

Comment: what happens if you call `destutter [1]`?

Comment: there is a typo in your code (hd1::hd2::to and to is a keyword - should be tl) . Then, the warning message gives you an indication why it is not exhaustive.

Answer (score 3):

Got it.

```
(* Remove contiguous duplicates from a lost *)
# let rec destutter list =
match list with 
| [] -> []
| [hd1] -> [hd1]
| hd1 :: hd2 :: tl -> 
    if hd1 = hd2 then destutter (hd2 :: tl)
    else hd1 :: destutter (hd2 :: tl)
;;
```

Comment: Normally if you program on a toplevel IDLE it would suggest the uncovered match case. Please mark your  own answer as correct too.